# How do I make each geom_point into a different color based on how it is classified in a column?

Tags: r, dplyr, ggmap

I have taken columns for latitude and longitude from a larger data set, and was wondering how would I make each geometric point a different color based on if it is in one of these categories for zoning.

```
> summary(dataset)
    Latitude       Longitude          Zoning  
 Min.   :40.66   Min.   :-73.92   R6     :18  
 1st Qu.:40.66   1st Qu.:-73.91   M1-1   : 5  
 Median :40.67   Median :-73.91   M1-4   : 5  
 Mean   :40.67   Mean   :-73.91   C4-3   : 4  
 3rd Qu.:40.67   3rd Qu.:-73.91          : 3  
 Max.   :40.68   Max.   :-73.90   C2-3/R6: 1  
                                  (Other):13
```

I used this below to take the subset that I need and make another dataset.

```
dataset <- (subset(dataset,select=c(grepl("Longitude|Latitude|Zoning",names(dataset)))))
```

I have been trying to use this below, but I am running into errors.

```
mymap <- get_googlemap("Brownsville, New York City", zoom=14)
ggmap(mymap) + geom_point(aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude), data= distinct(dataset), color = c("red","green3","blue","Yellow","orange","pink") [unclass(dataset$Zoning)],size=1.0)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I was planning on figuring it out for this application, and then doing it for other categories like Price per Sq. Foot, # of Units, Capitalization Rate. Year Built, Days Since Sold.

My professor sent me an example that does this with citibike data.

```
mymap <- get_googlemap("Madison Square Park, New York", zoom=13)
citibike1 <- citibike %>% group_by(lat, lon) %>% summarize(N=n())
ggmap(mymap) + geom_point(aes(x=lon, y=lat, colour=N, size=N), data=citibike1, alpha=0.5) +
scale_colour_gradient(low = "black", high="red")
```

[Makes dot color change based on how "hot" the citibike location is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwj7H.jpg)

Also, what does summarize(N=n()) mean here?

And can something along this be applied to categories like Year Built, and Days Since Sold.

Comment: `summarize(N=n())` is summarising your data to give the number of rows for each pair of `lat / lon` cooridnates (i.e., that which you've defined in `group_by`). The `n()` is `dplyr`s function for counting the number of rows.

Comment: And to get the colour, you'll want to do something like `aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, colour = Zoning)` - i.e, specify the variable/column to use for the colour inside the `aes()` function. Just like in the `citibike` example you posted

Comment: Thanks. I overlooked that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work for your data. It appears that the 'Zoning' variable is set as a factor so the colour output should be a set of discrete colours as opposed to a gradient like in your professor's example.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(ggthemes)

mymap <- get_googlemap("location of data points", zoom=13)

dataset %>% 
ggplot() + 
geom_point(aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, colour = Zoning)) + 
theme_map()
```

This code should also format it into a map like look. Please note that you need to enter the location of the data points in the get_googlemap() function and sometimes choosing the right zoom level for the points takes a bit of trial and error!

Let me know if you have any problems with this or if it doesnt meet your requirements. Thanks!

Comment: Great, thank you. If this answered your question it would be great if you could mark the question as answered, otherwise I am happy to assist further :)